# How to create Symbian style list views in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, symbian, qlistwidget, qitemdelegate

I've never done any item delegates in Qt before, and I think the documentation doesn't explain well about more complex delegates.

I need to create 2 styles of Symbian(^3) style lists

**Type 1:**

[image: Delegate style 1]

This is for common navigation lists, the icon and the lower label are optional.

**Type 2:**

[image: Delegate style 2]

This is for settings lists, where the pushbutton can be a toggle(on/off)-button or execute a context menu, etc.

How would I go on creating these sort of item delegates?

*Best Regards,
Rat*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to make something similar once. This is how I did it.

My delegate class declaration. As you can see it has a member: QLabel *label. You can add another label or a pushbutton, depending on your needs.

```
class MyItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    explicit MyItemDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyItemDelegate();
protected:
    void paint(QPainter *painter,
               const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                   const QModelIndex &index) const;
private:
    QLabel *label;
};
```

My paint() and sizeHint() methods.

```
QSize MyItemDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QSize();
    QVariant data = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole);

    label->setText(data.toString());
    label->resize(label->sizeHint());
    QSize size(option.rect.width(), label->height());
    return size;
}

void MyItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return;
    QVariant data = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole);

    // Not necessary to do it here, as it's been already done in sizeHint(), but anyway.
    label->setText(data.toString());

    painter->save();

    QRect rect = option.rect;

    // This will draw a label for you. You can draw a pushbutton the same way.
    label->render(painter, QPoint(rect.topLeft().x(), rect.center().y() - label->height() / 2),
                  QRegion(label->rect()), QWidget::RenderFlags());

    painter->restore();
}
```

Hope this is what you've been looking for. Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options ,

1) QML - This in my opinion is the best way to go and easier to achieve what you are trying to do.
[Link to Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/declarative-modelviews-listview-dynamiclist-qml.html)

This shows you how to use a Delegate for a listview.

2)QItemDelegate - Subclass QItemDelegate then Assign a this delegate to a listview ,
[Link to QItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qitemdelegate.html)

Comment: QML is not an option, as I want to maintain a native look and feel. I know I need to subclass QItemDelegate, the problem is that there is no documentation easy for me to comprehend regarding more complex delegates involving more than one type of ui element.